# Why can not call show method after cache in spark sql?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I created a dataframe called df in pyspark with HiveContext (not SQLContext).

But I find that after call df.cache() I will not be able to call df.show(). For example:

```
>>> df.show(2)
+--------+-------------+--------+--------------+--------+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+--------+-----+
|    bits|       dst_ip|dst_port|flow_direction|in_iface|ip_dscp|out_iface|    pkts|protocol|       src_ip|src_port|  tag|
+--------+-------------+--------+--------------+--------+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+--------+-----+
|16062594|42.120.84.166|   11291|             1|       3|     36|        2|17606406|    pnni|42.120.84.115|   14166|10008|
|13914480|42.120.82.254|   13667|             0|       4|     32|        1|13953516|   ax.25| 42.120.86.49|   19810|10002|
+--------+-------------+--------+--------------+--------+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+--------+-----+
only showing top 2 rows


>>> 
>>> df.cache()
DataFrame[bits: bigint, dst_ip: string, dst_port: bigint, flow_direction: string, in_iface: bigint, ip_dscp: string, out_iface: bigint, pkts: bigint, protocol: string, src_ip: string, src_port: bigint, tag: string]


>>> df.show(2)
16/05/16 15:59:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 14)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But after call df.unpersist(), the df.show() will work again

I do not understand. Because I think df.cache() is just caching the RDD for later use. Why the df.show() not work after call cache?

Answer (score 0):

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#caching-data-in-memory

Caching Data In Memory

Spark SQL can cache tables using an in-memory columnar format by calling sqlContext.cacheTable("tableName") or dataFrame.cache(). Then Spark SQL will scan only required columns and will automatically tune compression to minimize memory usage and GC pressure. You can call sqlContext.uncacheTable("tableName") to remove the table from memory.

Configuration of in-memory caching can be done using the setConf method on SQLContext or by running SET key=value commands using SQL.

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/6834/cache-table-advanced-before-executing-the-spark-sq.html#answer-6900

Comment: From your reply(The link). I can know 2 thing.  1. Cache on dataframe is lazy. The data being cached are those you read, right after the cache. 2. Cache on table is not lazy.    But this does not answer my question... Why the show() not working ?